# Get Index of a JSONObject with a certain key/value from JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have 2 JSONArray as responses from 2 HTTP requests. I need to concat both JSONArray responses into 1 array. There is a common field in both array "UniqueId". To ensure validity of data I need to put the values of 2nd array into the first but but comparing the UniqueId

so i.e I have Array1 & Array2
I need to find index of JSONObject with UniqueId == "2232" in Array1 and put to it the values of JSONObject with UniqueId == "2232" in Array2.

Is there any methods to find to index in a JSONArray by value of a certain field?

Comment: You iterate over the arrays and check the ids

Comment: show the code that you tried and which library are you using?

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart isn't there more efficient solution?

Comment: I don't believe so, sorry

Comment: @Deadpool judging from the class names I'd say he's using org.json

Comment: I am using org.json  @Deadpool